# SelectOutput based on condition (custom distribution)

Tags: anylogic

I'm building my model in Anylogic. I created  a population of agents with a custom distribution where I put in an option list. I put in 5 options(categories): A, B, C, D and E, each with its respective percentage. What I would like to do is for the agents to go to two different services based on the options(categories). I have a selectOutput in the model but I can't figure out what to put as a condition to make this happen, i.e. If the agent is A or B then I would like it to go to service_1 if it's C, D or E, I want them to go to service_2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple one once you understand conditional statements. Try this (assuming agents have a variable myOption that is A, B, C, D or E already drawn from your custom distribution):

[image]